# CakePHP pagination routing

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have the following two routes in my app for paging:

```
Router::connect('/news', array(
    'controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index','page' => 1
));

Router::connect('/news/page/:page*', 
    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'), 
    array('named' => array('page' => '[\d]+'))
);
```

The idea being that page 1 is `/news` and page 2 is `/news/page/2`

It just shows page one though... Any ideas what the issue is? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't need to use named parameters if your action accepts normal parameters:

```
public function index($page = 1) {} // defaults to page 1
```

Out of the box, this will make the following URLs work:

```
/news ---------> NewsController::index(null); // defaults to page 1
/news/index/1 -> NewsController::index(1);
/news/index/2 -> NewsController::index(2);
etc.
```

Now just add a route to map `/news/page/*` to the `index` action instead of the `page` action:

```
Router::connect('/news/page/*', array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Result:

```
/news/page/2 -> NewsController::index(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has a built in PaginationComponent for fetching the data and a PaginationHelper for pagination links in the view.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper

You don't need to set up routes for your pagination.

Ok, if you want to have custom routes, change it to this:

```
    Router::connect('/events', array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'index','page' => 1));
    Router::connect('/events/page/:page', array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'index'), array('page' => '[\d]+'));


    //find your data in params
    $this->request->params['page'];
```

Comment: Yes I know. But I wish to change the routing of them to be like in the post above instead of using `/news/page:2`